# LZW decoding function

Tags: python, compression, lzw

Here is a lzw decoding function, it decodes the input image. i dont understand  how it is doing this , 
i will appreciate it if anyone could explain it for me

```html
def lzw_decode(encoded_img, decoded_img):
    with open(encoded_img, "rb") as f:
        code_arr, shape = pickle.load(f)
    dictionary = dict()
    dict_size = 256
    for i in range(256):
        dictionary[i] = chr(i) 
     
    img = ""
    s = chr(code_arr.pop(0))
    img += s
    for k in code_arr:
        if k in dictionary.keys():
            entry = dictionary[k]
        elif k == dict_size:
            entry = s + s[0]
        img += entry    
        
        dictionary[dict_size] = s + entry[0]
        dict_size += 1
        s = entry
        
    img = [ord(x) for x in img]
    img = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint16).reshape(shape)
    cv2.imwrite(decoded_img, img)
```

Comment: How "well" it is doing?  This is an ambiguous statement.  What do you mean by this?

Comment: @Sanyash for sure i searched first, and i didnt understand it so i decided to ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be decoding arbitrary LZW data, but rather pickled data from another Python routine. Code for straight LZW data has the added difficulty of having to shift arbitrary-bitlength data into integers before processing.

Otherwise, the algorithm seems to be pretty much the same as Michael Dipperstein explains in <https://michaeldipperstein.github.io/lzw.html>:

1. Initialize dictionary to contain one entry for each byte.
2. Read the first code word from the input stream and write out the byte it encodes.
3. Read the next code word from the input stream.
4. If the code word is an EOF exit.
5. Write out the string encoded by the code word.
6. Concatenate the first character in the new code word to the string produced by the previous code word and add the resulting string to the dictionary.
7. Go to step 3.

Note that for dealing with codes that aren't yet in the dictionary, you append the first byte of the last-decoded value to that value, and add the new code to the dictionary.

Then the code takes all the integer values and uses `ord()` to turn them into Unicode before using some other imported code to `reshape` the data into an image.